# How to make ASP.NET MVC 4 application run securely using https

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web, https

I have made a ASP.NET MVC-4 web application. Now when i build my project it runs locally unsecurely(http). Now i want to run securely then how can make it to run securely.

Thanks,
Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

You need SSL sertificate for your site. in here you can get needed information:
[How to make a website secured with https](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205970/1534785)