# HTTPS redirect me to another web site

Tags: security, http, ssl, web, https

I have a domain name "http://wmsdardar.com". When I write the site with 'http' it appears normally, but when I add 's' to 'http' it's redirect me to another website.
Any idea on this?

Comment: The SSL certificate is not valid, response for https on your url is ssl_error_bad_cert_domain. In addition, the certificate expired on  21.03.2014 and is valid for some different domain names. Maybe this can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205325/how-to-make-a-website-secured-with-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, that's a shared hosting environment. You're getting the default HTTP site on the server, which appears to be www.dmk-tees.com.

Even with TLS and [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), you still get the default site. It looks like a possible configuration error at the server. Or its IIS 7.5 or below (because IIS 8 and above provides SNI).

You can see more from the command line. Below, a typical HTTP request is echo'd into OpenSSL's `s_client`. `s_client` provides the SSL/TLS (it doesn't care aboth HTTP or HTTPS). `-ign_eof` keeps the connection open to read the server's response.

---

```
$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: wmsdardar.com\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client \
          -connect wmsdardar.com:443 -tls1 -servername wmsdardar.com -ign_eof
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = "GeoTrust, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/serialNumber=PbSwEL0AVWvZHQnfa6mT8ByJDDNMN-AR/OU=GT48571904/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.dmk-tees.com
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/serialNumber=PbSwEL0AVWvZHQnfa6mT8ByJDDNMN-AR/OU=GT48571904/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.dmk-tees.com
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3048 bytes and written 372 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: FE78DF0E0450BF7CFE2A10EF9D0E8973047F1E52CD6FD81294860E5CC73ECDA1
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 9935D629B5D69AD7A00D5CD710BAD00AA1EB6CFC1AE961FF6EE5E3E488010E6C78C741B53546BED01428EC470B7A039A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 6d b5 cf 1d 7e 5b f9 56-68 63 1b 8b a3 a7 8a 6a   m...~[.Vhc.....j
    0010 - b8 88 58 4d 4b ec 1f d7-ad 54 23 a9 ca a2 60 b5   ..XMK....T#...`.
    0020 - cd 74 95 94 27 51 9b 85-f7 9e d9 09 61 48 e2 9d   .t..'Q......aH..
    0030 - 07 9d db e7 62 d9 09 93-80 5b 54 08 1f ed b9 68   ....b....[T....h
    0040 - 69 6b f8 ab e2 e3 84 6b-ea 7b 01 57 c6 46 02 47   ik.....k.{.W.F.G
    0050 - ec 54 1c e2 5c d9 4b d2-c6 91 06 32 23 1a e1 bf   .T..\.K....2#...
    0060 - f4 3c 14 cf 2f 78 f4 4d-b0 54 4e cb 3a b2 f5 f9   .<../x.M.TN.:...
    0070 - a6 a7 fb 92 13 82 77 28-31 20 e3 a2 e4 00 8e cc   ......w(1 ......
    0080 - 98 93 0a d3 52 e2 ed 3c-76 a5 dd 97 63 55 62 74   ....R..<v...cUbt
    0090 - b7 d2 65 54 86 84 d0 57-34 b8 49 b4 71 f3 ce a1   ..eT...W4.I.q...
    00a0 - cb 63 22 15 f5 aa 61 ad-0b 27 f7 c5 35 c7 7e 53   .c"...a..'..5.~S
    00b0 - 7d 1e 8c 9e 5c 4a 2f b5-87 f8 cc a9 ee 27 c0 22   }...\J/......'."
    00c0 - 80 1a c5 bf 8a 90 dd d2-2e 91 36 ed 99 d5 21 ca   ..........6...!.

    Start Time: 1408889370
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 24 Aug 2014 14:09:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 03 Apr 2014 00:51:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 19113
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="DMK" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="DMK, votre partenaire CUSTOM 100% MADE IN MOROCCO!" />
    <title>DMK, NEW BRAND MADE IN MOROCCO </title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon/dmk.ico" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39232008-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>

<body>



    <center>
<div id="splash">
<img src="images/dmk.png"/>
    <p>Votre partenaire CUSTOM! Coming very soon!</p>
  <br>


   <div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images"><ul>
<li><img src="data1/images/5899_493052687435359_661813899_n.jpg" alt="5899_493052687435359_661813899_n" title="5899_493052687435359_661813899_n" id="wows1_0"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/7148_491716044235690_1484254942_n.png" alt="7148_491716044235690_1484254942_n" title="7148_491716044235690_1484254942_n" id="wows1_1"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/7267_466965846710710_1201000904_n.jpg" alt="7267_466965846710710_1201000904_n" title="7267_466965846710710_1201000904_n" id="wows1_2"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/45951_541411132599514_654793214_n.jpg" alt="45951_541411132599514_654793214_n" title="45951_541411132599514_654793214_n" id="wows1_3"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/58833_470414406365854_790976645_n.jpg" alt="58833_470414406365854_790976645_n" title="58833_470414406365854_790976645_n" id="wows1_4"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/67380_454231071317521_1454483104_n.jpg" alt="67380_454231071317521_1454483104_n" title="67380_454231071317521_1454483104_n" id="wows1_5"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/69083_471776209563007_1378817459_n.jpg" alt="69083_471776209563007_1378817459_n" title="69083_471776209563007_1378817459_n" id="wows1_6"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/69090_468746103199351_192961920_n.jpg" alt="69090_468746103199351_192961920_n" title="69090_468746103199351_192961920_n" id="wows1_7"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/165244_475494079191220_1452366044_n.jpg" alt="165244_475494079191220_1452366044_n" title="165244_475494079191220_1452366044_n" id="wows1_8"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/181422_480637722010189_1376510602_n.png" alt="181422_480637722010189_1376510602_n" title="181422_480637722010189_1376510602_n" id="wows1_9"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/181493_483006415106653_569819191_n.jpg" alt="181493_483006415106653_569819191_n" title="181493_483006415106653_569819191_n" id="wows1_10"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/246932_495606270513334_699482726_n.png" alt="246932_495606270513334_699482726_n" title="246932_495606270513334_699482726_n" id="wows1_11"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/247774_479125848828043_56041832_n.jpg" alt="247774_479125848828043_56041832_n" title="247774_479125848828043_56041832_n" id="wows1_12"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/255439_481892025218092_1516607015_n.jpg" alt="255439_481892025218092_1516607015_n" title="255439_481892025218092_1516607015_n" id="wows1_13"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/401833_474496879290940_623927933_n.jpg" alt="401833_474496879290940_623927933_n" title="401833_474496879290940_623927933_n" id="wows1_14"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/426603_486693068071321_1727198949_n.png" alt="426603_486693068071321_1727198949_n" title="426603_486693068071321_1727198949_n" id="wows1_15"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/474706_494003457340282_1201682995_o.jpg" alt="474706_494003457340282_1201682995_o" title="474706_494003457340282_1201682995_o" id="wows1_16"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/529632_469693486437946_205388715_n.jpg" alt="529632_469693486437946_205388715_n" title="529632_469693486437946_205388715_n" id="wows1_17"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/534145_466743983399563_672338609_n.jpg" alt="534145_466743983399563_672338609_n" title="534145_466743983399563_672338609_n" id="wows1_18"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/535006_531646130242681_1465057530_n.png" alt="535006_531646130242681_1465057530_n" title="535006_531646130242681_1465057530_n" id="wows1_19"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/544154_453454184728543_1253347659_n.jpg" alt="544154_453454184728543_1253347659_n" title="544154_453454184728543_1253347659_n" id="wows1_20"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/547763_538308566243104_1450818813_n.png" alt="547763_538308566243104_1450818813_n" title="547763_538308566243104_1450818813_n" id="wows1_21"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/551509_473077432766218_1742872768_n.jpg" alt="551509_473077432766218_1742872768_n" title="551509_473077432766218_1742872768_n" id="wows1_22"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/555085_460632324010729_1153600139_n.jpg" alt="555085_460632324010729_1153600139_n" title="555085_460632324010729_1153600139_n" id="wows1_23"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/555100_467463563327605_259661499_n.jpg" alt="555100_467463563327605_259661499_n" title="555100_467463563327605_259661499_n" id="wows1_24"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/575377_488045851269376_1157314660_n.png" alt="575377_488045851269376_1157314660_n" title="575377_488045851269376_1157314660_n" id="wows1_25"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/946501_477219279018700_1518507724_n.jpg" alt="946501_477219279018700_1518507724_n" title="946501_477219279018700_1518507724_n" id="wows1_26"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/960103_485765711497390_1034123686_n.png" alt="960103_485765711497390_1034123686_n" title="960103_485765711497390_1034123686_n" id="wows1_27"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/969422_484551448285483_1907404375_n.png" alt="969422_484551448285483_1907404375_n" title="969422_484551448285483_1907404375_n" id="wows1_28"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/996537_516314481775846_1848025345_n.jpg" alt="996537_516314481775846_1848025345_n" title="996537_516314481775846_1848025345_n" id="wows1_29"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/998419_512672955473332_574508276_n.png" alt="998419_512672955473332_574508276_n" title="998419_512672955473332_574508276_n" id="wows1_30"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1000425_496944003712894_1979065040_n.png" alt="1000425_496944003712894_1979065040_n" title="1000425_496944003712894_1979065040_n" id="wows1_31"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1000984_508779055862722_1634218563_n.png" alt="1000984_508779055862722_1634218563_n" title="1000984_508779055862722_1634218563_n" id="wows1_32"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1001524_514653698608591_844771158_n.png" alt="1001524_514653698608591_844771158_n" title="1001524_514653698608591_844771158_n" id="wows1_33"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1001576_521792771228017_1815181099_n.png" alt="1001576_521792771228017_1815181099_n" title="1001576_521792771228017_1815181099_n" id="wows1_34"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1004632_507437975996830_1519568847_n.jpg" alt="1004632_507437975996830_1519568847_n" title="1004632_507437975996830_1519568847_n" id="wows1_35"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1004680_524860547587906_974480140_n.png" alt="1004680_524860547587906_974480140_n" title="1004680_524860547587906_974480140_n" id="wows1_36"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1005165_503646439709317_1954035292_n.jpg" alt="1005165_503646439709317_1954035292_n" title="1005165_503646439709317_1954035292_n" id="wows1_37"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1010368_510572782350016_2122157587_n.jpg" alt="1010368_510572782350016_2122157587_n" title="1010368_510572782350016_2122157587_n" id="wows1_38"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1013099_505149406225687_1315651320_n.png" alt="1013099_505149406225687_1315651320_n" title="1013099_505149406225687_1315651320_n" id="wows1_39"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1043994_502913453115949_1650423183_n.png" alt="1043994_502913453115949_1650423183_n" title="1043994_502913453115949_1650423183_n" id="wows1_40"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1044644_500907839983177_393230190_n.png" alt="1044644_500907839983177_393230190_n" title="1044644_500907839983177_393230190_n" id="wows1_41"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1044846_498891850184776_1887493836_n.png" alt="1044846_498891850184776_1887493836_n" title="1044846_498891850184776_1887493836_n" id="wows1_42"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1045213_501957583211536_596377504_n.png" alt="1045213_501957583211536_596377504_n" title="1045213_501957583211536_596377504_n" id="wows1_43"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1148777_519606618113299_727380990_n.png" alt="1148777_519606618113299_727380990_n" title="1148777_519606618113299_727380990_n" id="wows1_44"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1174543_525864804154147_935443287_n.jpg" alt="1174543_525864804154147_935443287_n" title="1174543_525864804154147_935443287_n" id="wows1_45"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1230003_540735789333715_588643703_n.jpg" alt="1230003_540735789333715_588643703_n" title="1230003_540735789333715_588643703_n" id="wows1_46"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/1238291_534037683336859_743962773_n.jpg" alt="1238291_534037683336859_743962773_n" title="1238291_534037683336859_743962773_n" id="wows1_47"/></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
<a href="#" title="5899_493052687435359_661813899_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/5899_493052687435359_661813899_n.jpg" alt="5899_493052687435359_661813899_n"/>1</a>
<a href="#" title="7148_491716044235690_1484254942_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/7148_491716044235690_1484254942_n.png" alt="7148_491716044235690_1484254942_n"/>2</a>
<a href="#" title="7267_466965846710710_1201000904_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/7267_466965846710710_1201000904_n.jpg" alt="7267_466965846710710_1201000904_n"/>3</a>
<a href="#" title="45951_541411132599514_654793214_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/45951_541411132599514_654793214_n.jpg" alt="45951_541411132599514_654793214_n"/>4</a>
<a href="#" title="58833_470414406365854_790976645_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/58833_470414406365854_790976645_n.jpg" alt="58833_470414406365854_790976645_n"/>5</a>
<a href="#" title="67380_454231071317521_1454483104_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/67380_454231071317521_1454483104_n.jpg" alt="67380_454231071317521_1454483104_n"/>6</a>
<a href="#" title="69083_471776209563007_1378817459_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/69083_471776209563007_1378817459_n.jpg" alt="69083_471776209563007_1378817459_n"/>7</a>
<a href="#" title="69090_468746103199351_192961920_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/69090_468746103199351_192961920_n.jpg" alt="69090_468746103199351_192961920_n"/>8</a>
<a href="#" title="165244_475494079191220_1452366044_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/165244_475494079191220_1452366044_n.jpg" alt="165244_475494079191220_1452366044_n"/>9</a>
<a href="#" title="181422_480637722010189_1376510602_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/181422_480637722010189_1376510602_n.png" alt="181422_480637722010189_1376510602_n"/>10</a>
<a href="#" title="181493_483006415106653_569819191_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/181493_483006415106653_569819191_n.jpg" alt="181493_483006415106653_569819191_n"/>11</a>
<a href="#" title="246932_495606270513334_699482726_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/246932_495606270513334_699482726_n.png" alt="246932_495606270513334_699482726_n"/>12</a>
<a href="#" title="247774_479125848828043_56041832_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/247774_479125848828043_56041832_n.jpg" alt="247774_479125848828043_56041832_n"/>13</a>
<a href="#" title="255439_481892025218092_1516607015_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/255439_481892025218092_1516607015_n.jpg" alt="255439_481892025218092_1516607015_n"/>14</a>
<a href="#" title="401833_474496879290940_623927933_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/401833_474496879290940_623927933_n.jpg" alt="401833_474496879290940_623927933_n"/>15</a>
<a href="#" title="426603_486693068071321_1727198949_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/426603_486693068071321_1727198949_n.png" alt="426603_486693068071321_1727198949_n"/>16</a>
<a href="#" title="474706_494003457340282_1201682995_o"><img src="data1/tooltips/474706_494003457340282_1201682995_o.jpg" alt="474706_494003457340282_1201682995_o"/>17</a>
<a href="#" title="529632_469693486437946_205388715_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/529632_469693486437946_205388715_n.jpg" alt="529632_469693486437946_205388715_n"/>18</a>
<a href="#" title="534145_466743983399563_672338609_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/534145_466743983399563_672338609_n.jpg" alt="534145_466743983399563_672338609_n"/>19</a>
<a href="#" title="535006_531646130242681_1465057530_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/535006_531646130242681_1465057530_n.png" alt="535006_531646130242681_1465057530_n"/>20</a>
<a href="#" title="544154_453454184728543_1253347659_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/544154_453454184728543_1253347659_n.jpg" alt="544154_453454184728543_1253347659_n"/>21</a>
<a href="#" title="547763_538308566243104_1450818813_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/547763_538308566243104_1450818813_n.png" alt="547763_538308566243104_1450818813_n"/>22</a>
<a href="#" title="551509_473077432766218_1742872768_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/551509_473077432766218_1742872768_n.jpg" alt="551509_473077432766218_1742872768_n"/>23</a>
<a href="#" title="555085_460632324010729_1153600139_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/555085_460632324010729_1153600139_n.jpg" alt="555085_460632324010729_1153600139_n"/>24</a>
<a href="#" title="555100_467463563327605_259661499_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/555100_467463563327605_259661499_n.jpg" alt="555100_467463563327605_259661499_n"/>25</a>
<a href="#" title="575377_488045851269376_1157314660_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/575377_488045851269376_1157314660_n.png" alt="575377_488045851269376_1157314660_n"/>26</a>
<a href="#" title="946501_477219279018700_1518507724_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/946501_477219279018700_1518507724_n.jpg" alt="946501_477219279018700_1518507724_n"/>27</a>
<a href="#" title="960103_485765711497390_1034123686_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/960103_485765711497390_1034123686_n.png" alt="960103_485765711497390_1034123686_n"/>28</a>
<a href="#" title="969422_484551448285483_1907404375_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/969422_484551448285483_1907404375_n.png" alt="969422_484551448285483_1907404375_n"/>29</a>
<a href="#" title="996537_516314481775846_1848025345_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/996537_516314481775846_1848025345_n.jpg" alt="996537_516314481775846_1848025345_n"/>30</a>
<a href="#" title="998419_512672955473332_574508276_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/998419_512672955473332_574508276_n.png" alt="998419_512672955473332_574508276_n"/>31</a>
<a href="#" title="1000425_496944003712894_1979065040_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1000425_496944003712894_1979065040_n.png" alt="1000425_496944003712894_1979065040_n"/>32</a>
<a href="#" title="1000984_508779055862722_1634218563_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1000984_508779055862722_1634218563_n.png" alt="1000984_508779055862722_1634218563_n"/>33</a>
<a href="#" title="1001524_514653698608591_844771158_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1001524_514653698608591_844771158_n.png" alt="1001524_514653698608591_844771158_n"/>34</a>
<a href="#" title="1001576_521792771228017_1815181099_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1001576_521792771228017_1815181099_n.png" alt="1001576_521792771228017_1815181099_n"/>35</a>
<a href="#" title="1004632_507437975996830_1519568847_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1004632_507437975996830_1519568847_n.jpg" alt="1004632_507437975996830_1519568847_n"/>36</a>
<a href="#" title="1004680_524860547587906_974480140_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1004680_524860547587906_974480140_n.png" alt="1004680_524860547587906_974480140_n"/>37</a>
<a href="#" title="1005165_503646439709317_1954035292_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1005165_503646439709317_1954035292_n.jpg" alt="1005165_503646439709317_1954035292_n"/>38</a>
<a href="#" title="1010368_510572782350016_2122157587_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1010368_510572782350016_2122157587_n.jpg" alt="1010368_510572782350016_2122157587_n"/>39</a>
<a href="#" title="1013099_505149406225687_1315651320_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1013099_505149406225687_1315651320_n.png" alt="1013099_505149406225687_1315651320_n"/>40</a>
<a href="#" title="1043994_502913453115949_1650423183_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1043994_502913453115949_1650423183_n.png" alt="1043994_502913453115949_1650423183_n"/>41</a>
<a href="#" title="1044644_500907839983177_393230190_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1044644_500907839983177_393230190_n.png" alt="1044644_500907839983177_393230190_n"/>42</a>
<a href="#" title="1044846_498891850184776_1887493836_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1044846_498891850184776_1887493836_n.png" alt="1044846_498891850184776_1887493836_n"/>43</a>
<a href="#" title="1045213_501957583211536_596377504_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1045213_501957583211536_596377504_n.png" alt="1045213_501957583211536_596377504_n"/>44</a>
<a href="#" title="1148777_519606618113299_727380990_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1148777_519606618113299_727380990_n.png" alt="1148777_519606618113299_727380990_n"/>45</a>
<a href="#" title="1174543_525864804154147_935443287_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1174543_525864804154147_935443287_n.jpg" alt="1174543_525864804154147_935443287_n"/>46</a>
<a href="#" title="1230003_540735789333715_588643703_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1230003_540735789333715_588643703_n.jpg" alt="1230003_540735789333715_588643703_n"/>47</a>
<a href="#" title="1238291_534037683336859_743962773_n"><img src="data1/tooltips/1238291_534037683336859_743962773_n.jpg" alt="1238291_534037683336859_743962773_n"/>48</a>
</div></div>

    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 680, height: 400,  navigation: true, delay: 5000, hoverPause: true });
  });
</script>



<div id="topic">

    <p>
    - T-Shirts & Designs 100% MADE IN MOROCCO!<br>
    - Possibilité de personnaliser vos vêtements.<br>
    - Commandes en ligne, par e-mail ou par téléphone.<br>
    - Livraison par Coursier ou via Amana Express.<br><br><br>

    </p>
</div>  

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdmk.tees&amp;width=292&amp;height=258&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;stream=false&amp;border_color=grey&amp;header=false&amp;appId=463721957034056" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</center>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```